# Finding y-values for corresponding x- values. Is interpolate right for this?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to find the y-values for the corresponding x-values (peaks).

[Chart for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtICC.jpg)

The peaks are being measured in time (x-axis) but I want to find the values they would have in price (y-axis).

I read online that interpolate could be used to find the y-values but the output I get comes out as the same as the y-values of the valleys. So im not doing something right

This is the code I used:

```
new_x_values = np.array([last_six_peaks])

peaks_y_value = np.interp(new_x_values, last_six_peaks, last_six_valley)
```

Comment: What do the variables you have contain? Is `last_six_peaks` the y-values of the previous 6 blue points in the plot? Does `last_six_valleys` contain the y-values of the previous 6 red points? Are these all 1d arrays containing, ot 2d containing both x- and y-values?

Comment: @MattPitkin the variables contain the last 6 values for the peaks and values. Peaks are the blue dots and valleys are the red dots

`last_six_peaks` contains the last 6 x-values and `last_six_valleys` contains the 6 y-values. Each is a 1d array.

Comment: For doing interpolation, you need pairs of x-y values that correspond to each other, you can then interpolate between those points. You seem to be suggesting that you have the x values of the blue points, but the y values of the red points, is that the case? If it is, then you can't perform an interpolation.

Comment: @MattPitkin yes that's the case. Thank you for clearing it up for me. Do you know of a way I could find the y-values of the blue points?

Comment: How did you get the y-values of the red points?

Comment: Do you have any information about the paler blue line?

Comment: Do you just have the image and you're trying to read values off manually, or do you have the data that created the image?

Comment: @MattPitkin I have the data that created the image. It's live ohlc data from EURUSD and i'm using 'time' for the x-axis and 'close' for the y-axis. The blue line is plotted using ohlc data and the red and blue dots are plotted after creating an array with the 'time' and 'close' and finding the maxima and minima

Comment: In that case, given that you were able to plot them, surely you have access to the y-values that you need anyway? Or am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just have access to the jpeg image, and you're having to read values off from it manually, I'd suggest the following. Open up the image in, e.g., MS Paint (or other image viewer/editor), which gives the x-y position in pixels, and get the y-pixel values of at least two of the y-axis tick marks. Doing this and putting them in Python lists, I get:

```py
# values at the lowest and highest y-tick marks
yticks = [1.884e9, 1.898e9]

# corresponding (approximate) y-pixel values
ypixels = [365, 52]
```

Use these to get the gradient of the y-axis, i.e., change in y-value per pixel:

```py
dydp = (yticks[1] - yticks[0]) / (ypixels[1] - ypixels[0])
```

Then you can get the y-pixel values of the blue peak points that you want (I'll do the two that are marked with a black line):

```py
import numpy as np

# y-pixel position of the peaks
peaks = np.array([91, 38])
```

and use the gradient to work out their y-values:

```py
yvalues = yticks[0] + dydp * (peaks - ypixels[0])

print(yvalues)
array([1.89625559e+09, 1.89862620e+09])
```

This is essentially linear interpolation for points between the values, and linear extrapolation for points outside the range (i.e., the upper most peak, which is above the last y-tick mark):